# Can't reinstall properly Pipewire

Tags: pipewire

After purging and reinstalling pipewire and wireplumber i ended up with these errors on systemctl

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODD5x.png)

It invloves RTkit and i tried to reinstall rtkit,dbus,polkitd but error message still remains. Should I forward this question to pipewire's gitlab and open an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by following these instructions

https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/wikis/Performance-tuning

Comment: Link only answers are not encouraged on AU, can you add some details to this answer?